# Install ASP.NET application packaged as a MSI

Tags: asp.net, windows-installer

[image]

I have created a MSI package from an ASP.NET application, when I run the MSI, it asks me toward which site I want to install the application. I have created a site especially for it, but when I install to this site, if I "Browse" in IIS, it doesn't work. What is the proper way to install and run the ASP.NET application with the generated MSI ? (web setup in VS 2010)

Comment: It doesn't even find an aspx page : which is normal because it is under a different folder. My question, first of all, is : do I use the right "method" to install my application ?

Comment: That's one of the available methods to install a web application. If that's the right method for your specific case I'm not sure with the info you provided. For example I tend to use an installer when it needs to be downloaded from a remote site in order to be installed or if you need to perform specific tasks when installing, for example changing a registry key. If you want to install an application in your own intranet and you don't have extra tasks to perform, you can use Web Deploy. This tool is installed at server level in the IIS and it can be used to configure IIS settings.

Comment: I just noticed that you are installing an application in a SharePoint site. If you are installing a SharePoint application, you should do it using a WSP package

Comment: No, I should've made a better screenshot, I'm testing on a sharepoint environment but in the end I won't use sharepoint